# Фильтр по нескольким категориям django

Tags: python, django

Хочу сделать сортировку по нескольким категориям, но выдает вот такую ошибку. Не совсем понимаю, в чем ошибка.

```
view:
class FilterByCategory(CategorySotr, ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Expense.objects.filter(category__in=self.request.GET.getlist('category'))
        return queryset

html:
<form action="{% url 'filter' %}" method="get">
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
    <h3>Category:</h3>
        {% for category in view.get_category %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="{{ category.name }}">
                <span>{{ category.name }}</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

url:
    path('expense/list/filter/',
         FilterByCategory.as_view(),
         name='filter'),
```

Comment: Лучше приведите код сюда. Чтобы лишний раз не переходить по ссылкам

Answer (score 2):

Ответ нашел. Нужно было изменить

```
<form action="{% url 'filter' %}" method="get">
```

на

```
<form action="{% url 'expenses:filter' %}" method="get">
```